I am trying to install Ubuntu 23.10.1 on USB it is getting stuck

I am using a 64 GB pen drive.
I have downloaded the 23.10.1 version of Ubuntu.
Done formatting both pen drives before installation (Both means 1: in which Rufus needs to be done and 2: In which I want to install Ubuntu)
The installation was running overnight still in the morning it was showing the same.



Can you give Ubuntu 24.04 a try?

You've specified a release, but not which actual product/ISO you're using of 23.10.  Ubuntu 23.10 Desktop offered two choices for example that used different installers, so using the legacy ISO that offers the ubiquity installer to me could make sense, but any 23.10 ISO using ubuntu-desktop-installer or subiquity makes little sense given the warning notices of EOL for 23.10 aren't that far away. You didn't specify if you're asking about Server, Desktop etc.


23.10 is obsolete now. Try 24.04.
You don't need to use Windows tools like Rufus. Just format the key with Ventoy and copy the ISO onto it. Easier, quicker, and supports lots of different ISOs on one key.

https://www.ventoy.net
